# Is it possible to inject PHP code via URI parameters?

Tags: php, code-injection

I want to learn more about (ethical) hacking since I'm a web developer and sometimes I get worried about my application's security.

Someone told me once the best way to learn is to try to hack real applications yourself, so I was playing around with an example here on my localhost. It's a really simple application I've built some time ago, and it has a file called api.php that goes like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');

if (isset($_GET["api"]) and $_GET["api"] !== "") {

  if ($_GET["api"] === "posts") {

    $url = "https://api.third-party.com/posts?q=". rawurlencode($_GET["post_id"]);

  } else if ($_GET["api"] === "users") {

    $url = "https://api.third-party.com/users?q=". $_GET["user_id"];

  } else if ($_GET["api"] === "tags") {

    $url = "https://api.third-party.com/tags?q=". $_GET["tag_id"];

  }

  $json = exec("curl -X GET ".$url);
  echo $json;

}

?>
```

I was trying to inject some PHP code using URI parameters. Something like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/test-app/api.php?api=users&user_id=5;print_r("success");}if(0){die();
```

My idea was that when my application would read the PHP code with the **user_id** parameter, it would do something like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');

if (isset($_GET["api"]) and $_GET["api"] !== "") {

  if ($_GET["api"] === "posts") {

   $url = "https://api.third-party.com/posts?q=". rawurlencode($_GET["post_id"]);

 } else if ($_GET["api"] === "users") {

   $url = "https://api.third-party.com/user?q=". 5;

   print_r("success");

 }

 if(0){

   die();

 } else if ($_GET["api"] === "tags") {

   $url = "https://api.third-party.com/tags?q=". $_GET["tag_id"];

 }


  $json = exec("curl -X GET ".$url);
  echo $json;

}

?>
```

But it's actually not working. All I get is a blank screen that's probably the result of an empty **$json** variable echoed.

Is this something possible to do? I also have a form that calls this script via ajax, could try to use it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec("curl -X GET ".$url);
```

Is executing a command, not running PHP.  Your shell most likely does not have a `print_r` command.  You could do something like:

```
http://localhost:8888/test-app/api.php?api=tags&tags=echo%20%22%3C?php%20print_r(\%22success\%22);%20?%3E%22%20|%20php
```

which would let you run

```
echo "<?php print_r(\"success\"); ?>" | php
```

Comment: I think it should be tags=|echo. But these strings always need some playing around. Great answer!

Comment: you can also use `eval()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php, as it helps to remain in the same context unlike `exec`, runs the piece of code as a completely different program. This makes `eval` function to access local variables. Another point is using `exec()` might be tricky. cause it is executed by the shell, there might be a case where shell throws an error like PHP command not found if PHP bins are located in a different location.
It might be also different for different OS platforms.